# Getting the total of refundable items for each order line

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I am trying to get the remaining OrderLines of a specific Order that can still be refunded.

So for each OrderLine of an Order, I want to calculate the sum of the **number** attribute of all existing RefundedLine refering to the Orderline.

This sum is then compared to the **OrderLine number** attribute : if it's equal, the line cannot be refunded anymore, if it's less it can be refunded (`sum(RefundedLine number) < OrderLine number`).

(There can be multiple RefundedLine referencing an OrderLine as an Order can have separate Refund till it's fully refunded).

### Here are my models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    pass

class OrderLine(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name="order_lines")
    number = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1,
                                      validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])

class Refund(models.Model):
    """ Is attached to one order, can concern multiples lines """
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.PROTECT, editable=False)
    lines = models.ManyToManyField(OrderLine, through='RefundedLine')

class RefundedLine(models.Model):
    """ Used for m2m """
    refund = models.ForeignKey(Refund, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    line = models.ForeignKey(OrderLine, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    number = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1,
                                      validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
```

---

### Now my attempts and their errors:

### Attempt 1 :

```
return OrderLine.objects.filter(order=self.order_id,
                                        number__lt=Sum(Subquery(
                                            RefundedLine.objects.filter(line=OuterRef('pk')).values('number')
                                        )))
```

> ERROR:  the column « cart_orderline.id » must appear in GROUP BY clause or must be used in an aggregate function
>   LINE 1: SELECT "cart_orderline"."id", "cart_orderline"."order_id", "...

*The error message is not exact as it has been translated by myself*

### Attempt 2 :

[From the Django doc itself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#using-aggregates-within-a-subquery-expression), no error but does not work as expected. If an OrderLine has no RefundedLine referencing to it, I get an empty queryset while it should return the OrderLine.

```
refunded_lines = RefundedLine.objects.filter(line=OuterRef('pk')).order_by().values('line')
        total_refunded_lines = refunded_lines.annotate(total=Sum('number')).values('total')
        refundable_lines = OrderLine.objects.filter(number__gt=Subquery(total_refunded_lines))
```

### Attempt 3 :

```
refunded_lines = RefundedLine.objects.filter(line=OuterRef('pk')).order_by().values('line')
        total_refunded_lines = refunded_lines.annotate(total=Sum('number', output_field=models.IntegerField())).values('total')
        refundable_lines = OrderLine.objects\
            .filter(order=self.order_id)\
            .annotate(refundable_number=Case(
            When(
                Exists(total_refunded_lines),
                then=Value(total_refunded_lines[:1]),
            ),
            default=Value(0),
            output_field=models.IntegerField()
        )).filter(refundable_number__gt=0)
```

Error message :

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'QuerySet'

As I try to loop over `refunded_lines`.

---

I have other attempts but I do not think that writing them would be benifical as the post is already clutered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F
OrderLine.objects.filter(
   # do your filtering here if you do not need the annotated value
).annotate(
    refunded_number=Coalesce(Sum('refundedline__number'),0)  # Annotate each OrderLine with the sum of the numbers of its refundedline
).filter(
    number__gt=F('refunded_number')  # Use F() objects to reference a field
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.

Not far from the result I expected.
1 problem, when their is no refundedline, I have None returned and so no OrderLine. Although if Sum('refundedline__number') is None it means it can be refunded. How to fix that ?

And I do not understand how we can reference 'refundedline__number'. No related name or field are designeted in my models, shouldn't it be refundedline_set ?

One last thing, it does not filter by order, I guess I can filter before the annotate for performance, or in your filter ?

Comment: I got my answer for the None problem (using Coalesce). I am gonna answer my own question.
Thank you a lot, I know a simple query could achieve what I needed. I spent 3 days fighting the Sum function and doing Subquery with other errors...

Comment: 1. I updated my answer to exclude OrderLines with no RefundedLine pointing back to it. If you just want to change None values to zero, you can use Coalesce as well. Or you can Coalesce then filter out the zero values

2. When accessing the related name in the query, you just use the lower case of the model name. You only use _set when accessing from the model. 

3. For filtering, you can do it before the annotate if you don't need the annotated field in your filter.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment ! I tried upvoting your answer and mark mine as accepted (as it has the corresponding behavior concerning the case where None is returned by the Sum(), regarding my initial question), but it does not work... (stackoverflow reputation point problem ?)
Anyway I got more than what I came for. Thank!

edit: need to wait 2 days to accept it, ok

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @GrandPhuba I could test and complete his answer

```
# Added the missing filter for the order
refundable_lines= OrderLine.objects.filter(order=self.order_id).annotate(
            # Added Coalesce because if no refundedline exist for the orderline, None will be returned and so the QuerySet will be empty, we do not want that
            refunded_number=Coalesce(Sum('refundedline__number'), 0) 
            # Annotate each OrderLine with the sum of the numbers of its refundedline
        ).filter(
            number__gt=F('refunded_number'),  # Use F() objects to reference a field
        )
```

Comment: I'd appreciate a vote up to my answer at the very least if it helped :)

Comment: As said in the comment of your answer, I tried multiple times, now it's upvoted I think (at least the vote stay when I refresh)
Getting error while trying to post this comment too :(